# Bootstrap clickable col

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 4 column within a row, that i want to be a link. Is this a good solution? 
Look at the snippet below.

```
<section id="projectResources">
    <div class="container">     
       <a class="row" href="#">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="project-resources">
                  <h4>Bacon ipsum dolor amet capicola hamburger chicken short ribs jerky ball tip pancetta chuck </h4>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
         </a>
     </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Do you want just a column as a link? Or you want all columns as link?

Comment: I want to have all columns on a certain page to link to different locations.

Comment: Then you can do something like that but put the <a> tag into <div> tags and use it only on the text or glyphicon.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it like this: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Yorkford/50osd4tm/)

```
<section id="projectResources">
<div class="container">     
   <div class="row">
         <a class="col-sm-3" href="#">
            <div class="project-resources">
              <h4>Bacon ipsum dolor amet capicola hamburger chicken short ribs jerky ball tip pancetta chuck </h4>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
         </a>
     </div>
 </div>
```